# Bootstrap 3. Помогите разобраться с колонками

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться с колонками, не могу сделать как на рисунке, битый час пробую, всё время средняя колонка, то больше то меньше остальных. Как сделать так, чтобы колонки с изображениями внутри располагались именно такой плиткой?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel=stylesheet>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left-col hidden-xs col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Pic1.jpg" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Pic2.jpg" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-col col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Pic3.jpg" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Pic4.jpg" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Pic5.jpg" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col hidden-xs col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Pic6.jpg" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Pic7.jpg" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.container-custom {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.container-custom .row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.container-custom .row [class*=col-] {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.container-custom .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 53.05%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-custom .thumbnail-1 {
  padding: 0 0 109.33%;
}

.container-custom .thumbnail-2 {
  padding: 0 0 53.33%;
}

.container-custom .thumbnail>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-custom {
  margin-top: calc(-53.33% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-custom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x410" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/370x200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/370x200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/370x200" alt="">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1 thumbnail-custom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x410" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x410" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/370x200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/370x200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/370x200" alt="">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1 thumbnail-custom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x410" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```